# Xunit Debug is Flaky

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm using Xunit for my unit tests. The application is using ASP.NET Core. I noticed some strange behaviors when I debug:

- Variables in the actual method (not the test method) shows null when it is not supposed to, and it has values after a while of debugging
- Another example is when debugged in the if statement, even though the if condition is return false, which means it shouldn't go inside the if statement, the debugger still goes inside..
- When the break point hits the helper method, it immediately ignores the helper method and jump to the next line. But it goes back to that helper method after a while.

Here's the dependencies of the unit tests project.
[image]

Does anyone see this behavior before?

Comment: What is the `Variables`? What is the `helper method`? Share us the debug screenshot. And how did you use Xunit with asp.net core?

Comment: @TaoZhou `variable` means something like `var variable = ClassA.MethodA()`. For your second question, I just created the Xunit project for the unit tests project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It is because the runsettings.json file contains some attributes that could break the debugger. Removing the following code works for me.

```
 <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
</DataCollector>
```